# Why this js file has types in it and why it works in a react js app but not in a react ts app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

This [js file](https://github.com/OpenGov/react-leaflet-heatmap-layer/blob/master/src/HeatmapLayer.js) has types in it and it works as expected in javascript react app but when I use it in a typescript react app it gives this compile error.

https://github.com/OpenGov/react-leaflet-heatmap-layer/blob/master/src/HeatmapLayer.js

```
'type aliases' can only be used in a .ts file.  TS8008

11 | import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
12 | 
13 | export type LngLat = {
   |             ^
14 |   lng: number;
15 |   lat: number;
16 | }
```

NOTE: I have tried changing file extension to .ts but this doesn't work, it gives me more than 50 errors in syntax, so I think this file is not typescript.

Comment: I suggest using an IDE such as WebStorm which handles all installation for you

Comment: What installation is necessary? If npx create-react-app nameOfTheApp --template typescript handles it

Comment: I'd suggest that CRA uses babel for ts. It simply strip all types from files and in ts setup it has additional ts process for typecheck. So when you use js setup it has no typecheck stage and types are ignored. And in ts setup it typecheck fails and it show error. Probably you can add `allowJs` to tsconfig to help it.

Comment: I have already add allowJs to true but still doesn't work, any suggestions? Is it possible that this file it's not typescript but using Flow (javascript framework for strict typing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook has introduced its own new typechecker called Flow , so if you see any react file with .js extension with 'Types' in them , then they are definitely type checked with flow, changing them to.ts file will throw error.

Another way to find if a file is type checked with flow is to look for '// @flow' on top of a file , this is one of the advantage using flow that it only type checks the files in the application which has added the above mentioned annotation in it.

For more info of FLow , please check out :
[https://reactjs.org/docs/static-type-checking.html#:~:text=Flow%20is%20a%20static%20type,Flow%20to%20learn%20its%20basics.](https://reactjs.org/docs/static-type-checking.html#:%7E:text=Flow%20is%20a%20static%20type,Flow%20to%20learn%20its%20basics.)

Answer (score 1):

### What is really happening:

The js file it is not just a js file but a js file with Flow. That is the reason why typescript is unable to compile the file.

### Solution:

There are two possible solutions:

1. Remove all the types from Flow and make the file a pure js file **(what I have done)**
2. Remove all the types from Flow and add types from typescript to have all the potential of typescript